# Initializing a matrix with random number from given range - python

Tags: python, numpy, random

How to initialize a matrix with random number (say 0 to 0.01)?

```
           A = numpy.random.rand(2,3)
```

This gives the result:

```
          >>A
               array([[ 0.45378345,  0.33203662,  0.42980284],
                      [ 0.2150098 ,  0.39427043,  0.10036063]])
```

But how to specify the range of random numbers ( 0 to 0.01)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers returned by `numpy.random.rand` will be between 0 and 1. Knowing that, you can just multiply the result to the given range:

```
# 0 to 0.001
A = numpy.random.rand(2,3) * 0.01

# 0.75 to 1.5
min = 0.75
max = 1.5
A = ( numpy.random.rand(2,3) * (max - min) ) + min
```

Or as DSM suggested:

```
A = numpy.random.uniform(low=0.75, high=1.5, size=(2,3) )
```

Comment: `np.random.uniform` might be simpler, esp. when the lower limit isn't zero.